# python urllib2 call to simple machine forum api

Tags: php, python, urllib2

Please find code below

```
import urllib2
post_id = raw_input('Please enter Id of the post to be migrated : ')
smf_url = 'www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=%s&action=.xml' %(post_id)
req = urllib2.Request(smf_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

when I remove `action=.xml` I am getting proper html content into my browser for give topic id. When I am tring to get xml feed, most of the times its giving me wrong data.

Can any one let me know if I should pass any other query parameter. Thanks

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: import urllib2

# reading post id from key board
post_id = int(raw_input('Please enter Id of the post to be migrated : '))

# building sms rest api url and triggering items
# out of this will be xml which should be converted to HTML
smf_url = 'http://10.65.221.180/smf/index.php?topic=%s&action=.xml' %(post_id)
req = urllib2.Request(smf_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there (otherwise it is not formatted in a way that is easy to read).

Comment: I edit question and added code, can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/bithon/python-simplemachinesforum

```
from simplemachinesforum.simplemachinesforum import SimpleMachinesForum

smf_url = "https://www.any-simplemachinesforum.com"
smf_user = "user_name"
smf_pass = "password"
smf = SimpleMachinesForum(smf_url, smf_user, smf_pass)

# 1 = board id:
smf.new_topic(1, "subject", "This is the message to post!")
```